# Executing stored procedure from sql developer vs executing from database server

Tags: plsqldeveloper

We are monitoring the performance of a stored procedure for experimental purpose.

This stored procedure read a single table and updates 5 table. While monitoring, I was expecting it to use network traffic. But to my surprise there were no network traffic.

The SQL developer is on my local machine. My assumption is it would use client service to connect to database and run the stored procedure on the database.

Kindly confirm my understanding and provide additional details.

Thanks.

Comment: You should also tag / mention what RDBS are you actually using. Oracle? SQL Server? MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Two things to consider...

1. You mentioned that SQL Developer is on your local machine.  Is the database there too?
2. SQL Server by default uses port 1433.  Are you watching that port?
3. As commented below, If you're using Oracle, check port 1521.
4. If you are using Oracle and TNS, check tnsnames.ora file to see if a port is specified there.

Comment: That sounds more like Oracle than SQL Server

Comment: Oracle's default port is 1521.

Comment: Ah...  SQL Developer VS Management Studio.  You're right.  He's probably using Oracle.

Comment: Its Oracle Database and it is not in my local machine and it connects through port 1521.